# Blur/focus event (delegeted) on inputs in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe on a page. In iframe there are few inputs in a form tag and more can be loaded via ajax.

I'm tring to bind blur or focus event to this inputs but it doesn't work. Other events, such as click works very well.

```
$(function () {
    $("iframe").each(function () {
        $(this).load(function () {
            $(this).contents().find("input").focus(function() { // works but this is only for existing inputs
                alert(1);
            });
            $(this).contents().find("form").on("click", "input", function (e) { // works
                alert(1);
            });
            $(this).contents().find("form").on("focus", "input", function (e) { // doesnt work
                alert(1);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To select inputs and forms inside the iframe try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("iframe").each(function () {
        $(this).load(function () {
            $(this).contents().find('body').find("input").blur(function() {
                alert(1);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That's strange; it works for me (I edited the answer with exactly the code that works for me). Can I ask about your version of jQuery?

Comment: Like I said .blur(...), .focus(...) working for existing inputs. on("focus", "input" ...) doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the problem: when you bind an event to a list of elements (like with the .find('input') ) you obviously bind it only to the ones that are currently in the dom. If you load new elements via ajax you need to bind the event after every ajax call. Something like: `$.load('newinputs.html',function(){$("iframe").each(function () { $(this).load(function () { $(this).contents().find('body').find("input").off('blur').on('blur',(function() { alert(1); }); }); }) });`

Comment: The problem is that I can't modify js with ajax code. I want to bind focus/blur event to inputs that are currently in dom and to this which will be added in future. I can do this with for example click event and it works $forms.on("click", "input", function (...)) but when i replace click with blur/focus it doesnt work.

Comment: Btw it is problem only with inputs in iframe, on normal pages it works.